# Searching for a particular image where either Batman or The Hulk are sitting on a throne

Tags: story-identification, marvel, dc

I am searching for an image where The Hulk is sitting on a throne, surrounded by items of all Avengers and other heroes. It was like a treasure room.
The Hulk also had the Infinity Gauntlet on his left hand, and if I am not mistaken, he had the Lanterns rings on his right hand.

I am tagging this question with both DC and Marvel because I am not 100% sure if the main character (the one on the throne) was The Hulk or Batman, however, I am 80% sure that there was hero's items from both universes.

Also, it is an image where the character is taken from face, not profile. It is also possible that it was a fan made image, since I saw it on 9gag.com a few years ago but I am not sure about that.

It looked a lot like this picture (same background) however, it was not Deadpool but either The Hulk or Batman, and there were way more trophies:

[image: Deadpool on the throne]

I really apologize for not being sure which character was on the throne, if more details are necessary, I would gladly add them if I recall them.

The hands looked quite like this:

[image: Batman with the Lantern rings and Infinity Gauntlet]

Comment: Was the Hulk perhaps bald, with a beard?

Comment: Yes that might be it

Comment: This is probably from a story featuring a future version of the Hulk, known as the Maestro. This Hulk was the last super-human; he almost certainly killed many of the former heroes we knew. He had a trophy room with souvenirs (including distinctive headgear of many heroes, Thor's hammer, Cap's shield, the broken remains of the Surfer's surfboard, etc). He originally appeared in *Hulk: Future Imperfect*. The trophy room is there, but no throne in that room, so your image is from something later.

Comment: After searching a little bit more, I believe the picture is from world war hulk, but I am not sure about it

Comment: Well after looking through the scans, it is definitely not from world war hulk

Comment: Maybe the series about Spiderman and the time gems? "Hulk is the smartest one there is!"

Answer (score 10):

Would this be the image you're looking for?

[image: The Maestro chilling on his throne, playing Yorick with Iron Man's helmet]

It's The Maestro, a version of the Hulk in a distant future where he has killed off all of the other heroes.

I don't see an Infinity Gauntlet, but the rest matches.

A similar image, but more frontal, is this cover of *Future Imperfect* of The Maestro:

[image: Future Imperfect - frontal view of The Maestro]

Comment: It clearly looks like it, however it was more of a front face image. The character was looking straight to the "camera", I'll edit that from my question, thank you

Comment: I added another image of The Maestro.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the image I am searching for is kind of a mix between the two. Like it is totally the view you posted in the second image, but with a room full of treasure like in the first.
Then again my apologies because I am not 100% sure if it was The Hulk or Batman (yeah I know, how could I not remember that)